# Class name not defined when instantiating

Tags: python

Learning Python, please go easy

I have removed all other methods defined in this class, here is the skeleton of whats left :

```
from random import randint

class CreditCardNumberGenerator:
    def __init__(self):
        print "Hello World"
        pass 

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        o = CreditCardNumberGenerator()
```

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "del.py", line 3, in <module>
    class CreditCardNumberGenerator:
  File "del.py", line 11, in CreditCardNumberGenerator
    o = CreditCardNumberGenerator()
NameError: name 'CreditCardNumberGenerator' is not defined
```

i have checked name, typecase and all possible SO thread, no help....can some one please advice??
I am pretty sure, its something very obvious which i am missing here!!! :\

Comment: this is not off topic, to a new user, who is coming from Java background, `indent` can be a big stuff to learn about, considering it handles the `scope`ing of the language...m surprised @martijn you put this on hold!!

Comment: Because an indentation question is not something that future users will find. On the Python syntax level this is a *typo error*; you indented a block too far here.

Comment: *you indented a block too far here* - exactly my point...i knew `indent` is important in python but no online tutorial mentions `too-far` inside can cause an issue...and things like these are difficult to debug if you are not aware of the stuffs.....! :)

Comment: Yes, and you have your answer. But your question is of no use to future visitors.

Comment: lol...m not gonna debate, its a valid question which some one else also can face if they do wrong indent or extra tab space...anyway...thanks!

Comment: Actually, I'm with Martijn on this - SO is place where questions should be "reusable" - even if this question is legit for new pythonistas, it will be no use for future readers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
   o = CreditCardNumberGenerator()
```

is too much indented - make it aligned to the same column as `class` and it should be OK.